# Three20-Popup a detail view controller and add new item to data source

Tags: iphone, three20

I am new to three20 and iphone development. I want to achieve a real simple function. I have a TTTableViewController which binds to TTListDataSource. I also have an add(+) button on top right corner. When that add button is pressed, I want to pop up a detail view for the user to enter the information. Then after the user navigate away from the detailed view by saving, the  TTListDataSource will be updated with user entered data.

I looked over the examples provided by Three20 library, and didn't find a good example for this. Can anyone provide some clue on how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to the ios development, I suggest you start with some basic & coredata tutorials before jumping into the three20 framework. Three20 is mostly about UI elements and easier to manage controllers navigation.

I believe Three20 doesn't has any storage / database framework, so you will have to use the standard core data apple provide. Here's a good example project with a table view & add feature:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405

After you have good understanding of the core data framework, it will easier to implement using three20.

Comment: you are right. But my question is about UI, I want a direction how to pop up a detailed view control, and update the TTListDataSource underneath

Comment: I use the standard present view controller function to show up the add controller and save everything in core data. once the user goes back to the TTTableViewController, i just refresh the entire data source instead of trying to add an item to an existing data source.

Comment: I see, so you use a UIViewController , not the TT**Controller to show up the add controller.

Comment: TTViewController extends the UIViewController, so you can present them as well